# Unable to open Git Bash

Tags: git-bash

Am trying to open Git Bash in any folder on a Windows machine and I get this error. How would one go about it?

`Error: Could not fork child process: There are no available terminals (-1).`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git bash Error: Could not fork child process: There are no available terminals (-1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799650/git-bash-error-could-not-fork-child-process-there-are-no-available-terminals)

Comment: It does not I get an error `ERROR: The process "ssh.exe" not found.`

Comment: which error you are facing `ERROR: The process "ssh.exe" not found.` or `Error: Could not fork child process: There are no available terminals (-1).`

Comment: @Moses then please edit your question, because that's not what you've asked.

Comment: I get the error `ERROR: The process "ssh.exe" not found.` when I try to use `taskill` as suggested in the post you shared

Comment: I tried `taskkill /F /IM ssh.exe ` as suggested but not seem to be working.

Comment: So I was responding to @Giorgi that the post (Git bash Error: Could not fork child process: There are no available terminals (-1)) does not answer my question.